# c# autologin website and view it

Tags: c#, authentication

Good morning everybody.

I simply want to automatical login to the website when I start the C# program.

So I started a new Webform project, simply added a button and a website frame.

Main:

```
namespace SG_Helper
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

And the form with a function behind the button:

```
namespace SG_Helper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string cookie = string.Empty;
        public WebClient wc = new WebClient();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string loginData = "loginname=***&loginpwd=***&switch=login";
            wc.BaseAddress = @"http://wbk2.schulterglatze.de/";
            string cookie = string.Empty;
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: identity");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
            wc.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
            string response = wc.UploadString("http://wbk2.schulterglatze.de/?ref=0", "POST", loginData);
            cookie = wc.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"].ToString();
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(response);
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = wc.DownloadString("http://wbk2.schulterglatze.de/masterfile/");
            //webBrowser1.Navigate("http://wbk2.schulterglatze.de/masterfile");
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure how to debug to find the correct way.
Can anyone tell me how to approach the problem?
Where do I need to debug to get the hint to the problem?

Thanks and greets
Daniel

Comment: -2 and no one says why!!!!

Comment: I didn't downvote and I'm not a mind reader but questions that end in "But it does not work" generally show very little effort to figure out *why* or showing what was attempted. Even worse, the likeliness of someone reproducing the issue without exposing sensitive information is extremely slim.

Comment: After some research I found out that you are trying to log in to a browser game. These games are usually funded by ads and probably have a mechanism to prevent the thing you are trying to achieve.